# draw Line graph in Monodeveloper in iPad

Tags: ipad, graph, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, linegraph

i am new to `iPad` developer,

i have created two or three iPad application in `objective c` using `Xcode 4`.

but now i want to create iPad application using `Monodeveloper tool` in `C#` language...

i want to try basic project of Graph,

for that i need some basic tutorial, which uses `Steema Chart`,

[here](http://www.steema.com/)
is information about stemma chart.

i searched in google but i didn't got any tutorial.

**Any help will be appreciated.**

***Thanks In Advance !!***

Comment: Please tell us what you did (e.g. downloaded the eval version ?), what code you wrote and what are the issues you're facing ? (e.g. can't build, can get the *right* graph, ...)